# Convolution of two distribution functions

Tags: probability, statistics

The convolution of two distribution functions $F_1$ and $F_2$ is

$F(t) = \int_{0}^{t} F_2(t-x) dF_1(x)$.

This can also be expressed as

$F(t) = \int_{0}^{t} F_1(t-x) dF_2(x)$.

The similar expression holds for survival function also. Now, I am reading a book which mentions that

$\bar F(t-u) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \bar F_1(t-s) f_2(s-u) ds$,

where $f_2$ is the density of $F_2$. I am unable to understand how are we getting the above step, esp. how is the upper limit changing to $\infty$. Can anybody please explain it?

Comment: I don't think your limits of integration are right, to begin with, on the convolution of two distributions.  It should be, I think, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$.  Some distributions won't actually require that whole range (depends on where/if they are zero for |x|>k), but normally the limits are infinite.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have changed the limits. Still, can you explain how are we getting that step?

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs.

Comment: I didn't get your point @joriki

Comment: You have three equations in your post that aren't inline. (These are called "displayed equations".) But you formatted them as inline equations by surrounding them with single dollar signs. That makes them come out cramped, harder to read and uncentred. Their formatting will be improved if you surround them with double dollar signs instead.

Comment: I wanted to know how that equation is coming, not the formatting.

Comment: Please check your index in your equation and clarify the relations between $\bar{F}, \bar{F}_1, f_2$.

Comment: In that case, I am not sure what you question is.  Can you restate it so that it uses 'general' limits of integration, (+/-$\infty$), and explain what $\bar F$ is?  Also, formatting will help.  Seee: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference